# How to show field collection items with comma separated in views?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have profile type *programmer*. This profile type having a field 'field_collection' type named language.

In the field collection we have two fields

1. Language
2. Year of experience

Now I am going to create a view that will show all the users associated with that profile type(*programmer*). I want to add an field(language) in that view which will have all the languages with comma separated.

NOTE : I don't want to show '*year of experience*' in the field, just want to show the '*language*' only. 
Ex : C++, PHP, JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

The basic setting for fields with multiple values actually has that as default. When you are adding the field into your view click on the multiple field settings tab and it will show you the functions to do just this.